# Extract int values from string

Tags: c, string

I have a incoming string like this :- `*DDMMYYHHMMSS#`  `DD` Stands for `Date`, `MM` stands for `month`, `YY` stands for `year`, HH stands for `Hour`...

Example `*021216213940#`  (Date : 2nd December, 2016  Time : 21:29:40)

How can I extract values from above given string and copy to int data type.

```
int Date,Month,Year,Hours,Minutes,Seconds;
```

Comment: `int Date = (str[1] - '0') * 10 + str[2] - '0'`.

Comment: Why multiply by 10?

Comment: You multiply by `10` to get the "tens". For example if the first digit is `2` then `2 * 10 = 20`.

Comment: For example if incoming string is like `*021216213940# (Date : 2nd December, 2016 Time : 21:29:40)`. How to extract the date and month?

Comment: @freestyle has it.

Comment: @freestyle - post that as an answer... :-)

Comment: Yes got it. So date can vary from 01-31. Multiplication is necessary, is there any not to multiply when date is  between 01-09?

Comment: OMG. My first comment was just off-the cuff, not a good answer, but if you multiply by 10 anyway, then you would not need any special cases, like, "do I need to multiply by 10 here"..

Comment: Do you care if the final `#` is missing?   What about other errors like the 13th month or non-numeric input?

Comment: There won't be non numeric input. `#` presence doesn't matter. There are 12 months. What error you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the content of your string you need to convert to (a two digit) decimal, which is a [ten-based positional system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal).

For example to extract the first two digits you use subscript `operator[]`, i.e. `str[1]` and `str[2]`, to convert from `char` to `int` you subtract `'0'` character utilising [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character ordering and finally to ensure correct position of the digits you multiply by `10`:

```
int DD = (str[1] - '0') * 10 + str[2] - '0';
```

---

Comment: Random name of a variable, the first two digits of your string, it should be day, I guess.

Comment: Is everything else comprehensible enough? Do you need further elaboration?

Comment: Um, That's enough I guess.

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use scanf family functions, like this:

```
char *incoming = "*021216213940#";
int day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds;
if (6 != sscanf(incoming, "*%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d#", &day, &month, &year, &hours, &minutes, &seconds))
{
    ... /* handle invalid input here */
}
```

Comment: +1. Just like to add that `sscanf` can be used if the input is already located in a string. Like `char* p = "*021216213940#"; if (6 != sscanf(p, "*%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d#", &day, &month, &year, &hours, &minutes, &seconds)) { /* error handlind */ }`